# logstash - store content of fields in dynamic lists

Tags: logstash

Purpose: Track privileged user activity in Windows logs.

Logic:

If logon event contains *token_elev %1937 or %1938* save the logon_id (hex value) to a dynamic priv_logons list.

For subsequent events, *if* the logon_id in the event matches one of the entries in priv_logons list, add a 'privileged' tag to the event.

When receiving a logoff event with one of the logon_ids saved in priv_logons list, remove it from the list.

Is this doable in LogStash? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Not with Logstash alone.

Logstash does not maintain internal states or data objects in between events, it is simply a parsing engine.

Logstash may help you create this kind of solution by doing the parsing work and then passing clean and sensible data to a program which performs the logic you are looking for.